# Chrome extension hide address bar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to hide the address bar using Chrome Extensions?
I would like to hide the address bar and toolbar but still be able to click on links that can be opened in a new tab. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Only possible in a [`popup` or `panel` window](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create), both don't have tabs.

Comment: is it possible to make a tab into such a `popup` or `panel` window?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. For now Chrome doesn't have that kind of extension APIs.

You can see the list of extension APIs from [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index)

Suggestion: How about just make  the tab fullscreen?

```
chrome.windows.update(windowId, { state: "fullscreen" })
```

Comment: Will this make it possible to see that you have several tabs?  Or is it more one tab in fullscreen making it like a fullscreen window without tabs ?